# Exclude key from WordPress query

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$counter = 1;
$grids = 3;
$titlelength = 30;

$args=array (
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby'    =>  'date',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
     array(
     'taxonomy' => 'herkunft',
     'field' => 'slug',
     'terms' => 'deutschland'
     ),
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'herkunft',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => 'oesterreich'
     ),
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'herkunft',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => 'schweiz'
 ),
)   
);
```

See my query above. Is it possible to exclude `key => 'product_fake'` (which is part of the custom post type `'products'`) from the query and how would I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by which is part of the custom post type 'products'

Comment: There is the custom post type products and some products are so called „fake products“. So it's key => 'product_fake'